# how to Find derivative of a LHS expression with respect to a variable in the RHS of a Sympy Eq

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have an eq1 such that

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, plot, Eq, diff
a, b, X, Y, U = symbols('a b X Y U')
eq1 = Eq(U, X**a*Y**b)
```

$U=(X^a)(Y^b)$

but When I run diff(eq1 , X)
the differential does not evaluate I merele just get the DU/DX symbol but not evaluated

[image]

I know I could defined the function as
`U = X**a * Y**b`
and easily compute `diff(U)`

but printing the U expression will not look nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised that you even get what you got. In general, algebraic operations on `Eq` are not supported.

```py
>>> from sympy import Derivative
>>> ediff=lambda e, *x: e.func(Derivative(e.lhs,*x), e.rhs.diff(*x))
>>> ediff(eq1, X)
Eq(Derivative(U, X), X**a*Y**b*a/X)
```